# NextJS react-calendar duplicate dates selection issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, react-calendar

I'm developing a calendar component using NextJS, typescript, tailwindcss, react-calendar library and I ran into a problem with duplicate dates in the calendar when selecting a date range. I added exceptions for duplicate dates elsewhere, but I couldn't remove duplicate dates in the next month - all dates of the month are duplicated except for the selected dates, and except for the dates of another month.

Also there is a problem with inability to select current day, month, year in the calendar.

Kindly help to understand and fix this problem.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/young-hill-63l7v7

[image: initial]
[image: selected-dates]
[image: duplicates]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import ReservationModal from './ReservationModal';

import '../calendar/CusCalendar.css';

const CusCalendar: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState<Date[] | Date | null>(null);
  const [showCalculation, setShowCalculation] = useState(false);
  const [showReservationPopup, setShowReservationPopup] = useState(false);
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(new Date());

  const startDate = Array.isArray(selectedDates) ? selectedDates[0] : null;
  const endDate = Array.isArray(selectedDates) ? selectedDates[1] : null;
  const pricePerNight = 100;

  const nights = startDate && endDate ? Math.floor((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) : 0;
  const totalPrice = nights * pricePerNight;

  const isDateSelected = (date: Date) => {
    return startDate && endDate && date >= startDate && date <= endDate;
  };

  const handleDateChange = (date: Date | Date[]) => {
    if (!startDate || (startDate && endDate)) {
      setSelectedDates(Array.isArray(date) ? date : [date]);
    } else {
      if (Array.isArray(date) && date[0] >= startDate) {
        setSelectedDates(date);
      } else {
        setSelectedDates(Array.isArray(date) ? date : [date]);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleCalculate = () => {
    if (startDate && endDate) {
      const numberOfNights = Math.floor(
        (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
      );
      const totalPrice = numberOfNights * pricePerNight;
      setShowCalculation(true);
    }
  };

  const handleClearDates = () => {
    setSelectedDates(null);
  };

  const handleReserve = () => {
    if (startDate && endDate) {
      setShowReservationPopup(true);
    }
  };

  const handleReserveClick = () => {
    setShowReservationPopup(true);
  };

  const handleMonthChange = (newMonth: Date) => {
    setCurrentMonth(newMonth);
  };

  return (
    <div className="text-start border-4 rounded-[30px] solid border-[#ebebeb] w-[478px] h-full">
      {!showCalculation ? (
        <div>
          <div className="text-[28px] font-bold text-[#313131] leading-normal uppercase pl-7 pt-7 pb-3">SELECT CHECK-IN DATE</div>
          <div className="text-[18px] font-normal leading-normal text-[#969696] pl-7 pb-7">Add your travel dates for exact pricing</div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
      <div className="mx-7">
        {!showCalculation ? (
          <Calendar
            onChange={handleDateChange as any}
            selectRange={true}
            tileContent={({ date, view }) => {
              if (view === 'month') {
                if (selectedDates === null || isDateSelected(date)) {
                  return null;
                } else if (date < new Date()) {
                  return null;
                } else if (
                  (startDate && endDate) &&
                  (date.getMonth() !== startDate.getMonth() || date.getMonth() !== endDate.getMonth())
                ) {
                  return null;
                } else {
                  return (
                    <div className="">
                      {date.getDate()}
                    </div>
                  );
                }
              }
              return null;
            }}
            tileDisabled={({ date }) => date <= new Date()}
          />
        ) : null}
      </div>
...
```

Comment: Could you [import your project](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/sandboxes/cli-api) into codesandbox.io (or a similar service)? What you shared is not enough to repro the problem and therefore not really useful to anyone trying to find a fix for it. As much as possible, make the [mcve] actually minimal, by removing any code which is not related to the question, while making sure the bug is still reproducible.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/young-hill-63l7v7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `else` clause in `CusCalendar.tsx:102` seems to [solve the problem](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/festive-lewin-vdp6qs?file=%2Fapp%2FCusCalendar.tsx%3A102%2C18)***<sup>1</sup>***.

However, it's up to you to determine if this has other implications in your project, the business logic is not entire clear (at least to me).

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - Upon further inspection, I noticed you're returning `null` for all of those conditions and it appears removing `tileContent` altogether fixes the problem. I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve there, but that's clearly the root cause of the bug.

Comment: Well, for once, I don't understand why you have a bunch of conditions in which you return `null` for `tileContent` and why you return a `<div>` containing current day if none of the conditions are met? What are you trying to achieve? As for asking additional questions, [SO] rules are you have to ask each question separately, so they can be indexed and remain useful for users having a similar problem. If you ask multiple questions in one, that's less likely to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: Thank you again! By returning `null` in all these conditions in `tileContent`, I was trying to hide all possible dates that I had duplicated before this one

Comment: I've updated my sandbox with a `tileDisabled` which includes current day.

Comment: Big help! Thank you so much!
If you're interested and don't mind, I'd be extremely grateful if you could look at my other questions, because they still haven't been resolved...

Comment: I'm out of time for the day, I'll give them a look tomorrow and, if there's anything I can answer, I will.